# Parsing JSON using php and curl command from an API

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse the JSON information I get, using PHP, from a powershell script that uses a form on the web-page to send an API request that searches a test database and returns a set of clients and I want to eventually put these into a dynamically populated table.

The issue i'm having is that i'm not able to just print out a specified part of the JSON array onto the page

The JSON i'm getting looks like this:

```
[{
    "id":          2,
    "firstname":   "Edward",
    "lastname":    "Franks",
    "companyname": "",
    "email":       "EdwardFranks@mail.com",
    "datecreated": "2018-10-09",
    "groupid":     0,
    "status":      "Inactive"
},
{
    "id":          1,
    "firstname":   "Frank",
    "lastname":    "Ti",
    "companyname": "U Consultation",
    "email":       "frank@u.co.uk",
    "datecreated": "2018-10-08",
    "groupid":     0,
    "status":      "Active"
}]
```

We get this information by searching a name or an email address associated with the account.

HTML:

```
<form method ="post" action = "veeam.PHP">
    <ul class="form-style-1">
        <li>
            <label>Name or Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="clientsearch" class="field-divided" placeholder="Enter details" />
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" onSubmit="invokeapi()"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
function invokeapi() {
    $client = $_POST["clientsearch"];

    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $url = 'http://apiURL/?command=Check-ClientWHMCS%20'.$client;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $clientlist = (array) json_decode($output, true);
    print_r($clientlist);
    echo $clientlist[0]["id"];
}

if(isset($_POST['clientsearch'])) {
    invokeapi();
}
```

When I use the `json_last_error` command it says there's no issue with the JSON and when I use the `isArray` command in PHP it says that the variable IS and array so i'm quite stuck on where to go next.

I get some output on the webpage but it just prints out the entirety of the JSON result on a single line with `Array ([0] => 1)` at the end of it.

Any help on this issue would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to type-cast the result of json_decode to an array? Have you first of all verified whether $output actually contains what you think it does?

Comment: I type-casted it because otherwise it wouldn't return an array and that's what I assumed I needed. When I echo out $output it adds a 1 at the end of the JSON data that I never noticed. This means that the data isn't in that variable doesn't it? The question is, why isn't the curl data being put into the output variable for me to use now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, now curl_exec() will print out the result immediatly instead of returning it as a string in other words `$output` will not be filled.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Also your cast to an array with json_decode with true is not necessary.

Comment: This has helped a lot since now I can specify which client in the JSON I want by specifying the index. If I put $clientlist[0] it shows all of the data associated with that part of the array. How would I just pull the ID, per se, of that customer since if I type $clientlist[0]['id'] I just get an error saying: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: is it that you cast because your array has indexes with objects? in that case maybe a cast was needed so readd `(array)` but i am not sure

Comment: I'll have another look around the internet but the hard part is over now. Thank you so much for your help!